# Suitable high voltage source for a cathode ray tube

Tags: high-voltage

I'm looking for a suitable high voltage source for the electron gun of a cathode ray tube (CRT.) Slightly simplified the schematic of a CRT looks like:

[image: CRT]

[This eBay listing](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/254357227885?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&itemid=254357227885&targetid=1279076611369&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=1007053&poi=&campaignid=14727339348&mkgroupid=127909237815&rlsatarget=pla-1279076611369&abcId=9300672&merchantid=113070480&gclid=CjwKCAiA4KaRBhBdEiwAZi1zziPY27NhMXONyrhTIQS7PAeDHPmdQuSRFlmz7P_1uzqtlBN9S0MSHBoCaFYQAvD_BwE) seems to offer something that might be suitable:

[image: HVS]

---

- mains feed,
- adjustable high voltage (DC) output,
- fairly detailed description/manual.

Re. the latter, I'm a chemist, know little about HVS and on top of that this manual is in 'Chinglish'. E.g. little is said about power output or maximum output current (obviously I don't need any current at all.)

I understand that the part of the accelerating anode closest to the thermionic cathode needs to be at 0 V. How do I achieve that? Wild guess: earth that part of the anode?

---

**Edit:**

Here's a picture of the CRT in question. It's a Soviet-era CRT, probably from a piece of scientific equipment. Right and below it its the socket:

[image: CRT]

Comment: You actually **do** need current for your tube.  More current = brighter trace on the phosphor from the electron beam.

Comment: Yes, on the cathode. Not on the accelerating anode though.

Comment: @Gert The electrons that the cathode emits need to flow *somewhere*. They flow into the final anode. The beam current flows from the cathode to the final anode on the face of the screen. You don't show it, but it's there all right. If the cathode is directly heated, then the beam current flows through the heater as there's no separate cathode. If the cathode is indirectly heated, the beam current does not flow through the heater, since the cathode electrode is galvanically isolated from the heater.

Comment: The tube is physically quite small. Are you absolutely sure that 7kV is the accelerating voltage? That's a lot, and this tube would be used for some high-frequency display to necessitate such a voltage... if it's a display tube to begin with. **Please add the part number of the tube to the question** - otherwise we can't know how far your "interpretation" is from the application circuit of such a tube. For one, the tube you show has no phosphor on the glass envelope. If there's a screen, it's the metallized translucent disk of the final anode.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thank you. I see what you mean but have difficulty seeing how the electrons get from the screen to the 'final' (?) anode. Electronics are still like Chinese to me!

Comment: The recommended anode voltage is 6 kV (I misremembered). It was advertised as an **ILD3-L Rare USSR CRT VFD Indicator Tube Green + Socket NOS**. The phosphor is at the 'flat' and, opposite the gun. It's supposed to phospho green. The metallized bit is the barium getter, I think.

Comment: http://www.r-type.org/exhib/aaa1718.htm

Comment: @BruceAbbott Wow, that's fantastic, really didn't know there is something of a database on these things. Now I can check against the (Russian language!) spec it was advertised with. Thanks a bunch! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no PE earth protection here.

- CRT TV's only used  2 pin plugs and relied on insulation.
- White = 0V Red = KV. (uncalibrated)
- There would be some series chain of resistors on the output to scale down the voltage perhaps 1k:1 to the RED LED connector to measure it. (as NECESSARY to prevent failure, start from minimum voltage.)
- There are 2 trimpots for voltage and current required by the flyback oscillator to drive the load capacitance and raise grid kV to accelerate electrons
- heater current (LV) is NOT SHOWN.
- shield around heater is cathode = -ve or 0V ref
- grids in tube is anode = +ve

more detail
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cathode-ray_tube

- old CRT's are abundant in junk yard recycling areas, many with > 200 kHz BW and working HVDC supplies useful for XY experiments.
- Plastic caps can store HV for a long time, (minutes) be careful

Comment: Hi and thanks! My CRT is not for a TV CRT (photo added)|Does 3rd point only relates to measuring voltage (scaled down)?| Point 5: did you mean 'not', instead of 'now'?|